# applescript, included do shell script not working

Tags: applescript

I'm not a developer but try to use applescript to do some work for me.
I have a small script to find a application and kill it.

I have read many articles but not found a solution.

```
tell application "System Events"

    set x to first process whose name is "Blotter"
    return unix id of x

end tell

try
    do shell script "kill " & x
end try
```

I get the process id as a result.

tell application "System Events"
get process 1 whose name = "Blotter"
--> application process "Blotter"
get unix id of application process "Blotter"
--> 34990
end tell

Ergebnis:
34990

But I'm not able to kill it...

I would be really grateful for a tipp. Thanks

Comment: Why AppleScript? Just use Terminal: `killall Blotter`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I use AppleScript because I want to run the job one a day. And this is just the start of the job to do...

Comment: Try sending a stronger signal than `SIGTERM` (the default), with `do shell script "kill -9 " & x`. or equally using the name instead of number... `kill -s KILL PID`

Comment: does not work either, somehow i guess the kill comand is not executed...
i can kill it in another applescript:
`try
 do shell script "kill 34945" 
end try`

Comment: The `return` statement does just that - it returns from the script, which ends it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set proc to first process whose name is "Blotter"
    set procID to unix id of proc
end tell

try
    do shell script "kill " & procID
on error errstr
    display alert errstr
end try
```

by using `return` you' rent getting the unix id of the process, you're merely ending the script. Put the unix id in a variable, and then use that variable in your do shell script.

Comment: this works, thank you so much....

now i will try to get the rest together....